# Coalesce not returning 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a stored procedure to return the total sales for a manager and anyone who reports to them. I want it to return a total of zero if there are no sales but it is currently not returning anything if there are no sales in a given period.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_ManagerTotalSales @managerID INT,
                                   @beginDate DATE,
                                   @endDate   DATE,
                            @group VARCHAR(15) = 'total'

AS
BEGIN 

SELECT          
    FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName AS Name,           
   COALESCE(SUM(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity), 0) AS TotalSales
FROM 
   dbo.Employees e
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
WHERE 
   (e.EmployeeID = @managerID OR e.ReportsTo = @managerID)
   AND o.OrderDate >= @beginDate
   AND o.OrderDate <= @endDate                            
GROUP BY 
   e.FirstName,
   e.LastName                     
END
```

Comment: Your `where` filters out the employees that do not have an order. Add the conditions to the join (specifically `o.OrderDate`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT          
        FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName AS Name,           
       COALESCE(SUM(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity), 0) AS TotalSales
    FROM 
       dbo.Employees e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID  
          AND o.OrderDate >= @beginDate
          AND o.OrderDate <= @endDate 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    WHERE 
       (e.EmployeeID = @managerID OR e.ReportsTo = @managerID)
    GROUP BY 
       e.FirstName,
       e.LastName
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I came up with in response to an above comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `group by` . . . if no rows match the condition, no rows are returned.

One method is:

```
with g as (
      <your query here>
     )
select g.*
from g
union all
select name, totalsales
from (select NULL as name, 0 as totalsales) x
where not exists (select 1 from g);
```